# Tensorflow or general neural network: One of my loss is too high! (loss = u + v)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I made my custom loss value which is u + v and u is MSE between prediction value from my neural network and training output value. v is a value yielded from an equation related to gradient of the prediction value with regard to input value.

The problem is depending on input, v yield huge number compared to u.

How can I make the amplitude of v similar to u?

---

My input is not normalized. Instead, I put normalization layers so, eventually it is normalized. The reason why I insert normalization layer and v yield huge number is because of gradient of the prediction value with regard to input, which is not normalized and I need this. If I put 'good' value as a input such as 0~1. My NN works fine. However, when I insert 'real' (physics related) value, it does not work due to huge value of v. and this v value will not decrease until the network is well trained for u.
I also tried to set loss only with regard to 'u' and then later include 'v'. However, because of high value of 'v', the system does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should still normalize your input despite having normalization layers.

If one of your losses (more accurately, the gradient of the loss w.r.t. to parameters) is too high, you can just scale by it by a constant, say `loss = loss/100`. The math works out just fine to scale the gradient by `1/100`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am wondering why I still need to normalize my input data though there is a normalization layer? The input data is passing to hidden layers via the normalization layer.

Comment: @ENHorse Normalization layer typically normalizes per batch while data normalization is per dataset. Do you mean input -> normalization -> linear? I don't think I have ever seen that, but input -> linear -> normalization much more often.